# close connection with uwsgi and websockets

Tags: python, websocket, uwsgi

Lets say I have this basic WebSocket application with uWSGI:

```
def application(env, res):
    uwsgi.websocket_handshake(env["HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_KEY"], env.get("HTTP_ORIGIN", ""))
    while True:
        msg = uwsgi.websocket_recv()
        uwsgi.websocket_send("OK: " + msg)
```

How can I close the client gracefuly? For example when I do

```
def application(env, res):
    uwsgi.websocket_handshake(env["HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_KEY"], env.get("HTTP_ORIGIN", ""))
    while True:
        msg = uwsgi.websocket_recv()
        if msg == "exit":
            break
        uwsgi.websocket_send("OK: " + msg)
```

this seems to work, however I receive

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

in uWSGI which is kind of understandable since it's trying to iterate over `application(...)` just like it would over HTTP (compatibility??). To avoid that I've added `yield None` at the end:

```
def application(env, res):
    uwsgi.websocket_handshake(env["HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_KEY"], env.get("HTTP_ORIGIN", ""))
    while True:
        msg = uwsgi.websocket_recv()
        if msg == "exit":
            break
        uwsgi.websocket_send("OK: " + msg)
    yield None
```

which fixes the error but looks like a nasty hack. Besides there might be some side-effects I'm not aware of (does uWSGI send something to the client anyway??). Or am I wrong?

So how to handle this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just

```
return ['']
```

and you will be fully WSGI compliant without sending additional data to the client

Comment: Works, awesome. Can you just let me know where you found this information? I couldn't find it anywhere.